# logging separation in an ear application

Tags: logging, logback, log4j2

I have an ear containing some jars, wars etc. I need to have separate logging configuration (like destination etc.) for each war(s), jar(s).

I was going through http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/logsep.html    and  http://logback.qos.ch/manual/loggingSeparation.html .

But, things are unfortunately  not clear enough for me.

Can somebody please purvey a better reference or better logging solution

Comment: What is your Application Server (Glassfish, Websphere, Weblogic)?

Comment: @PaulVargas, JBoss, for the time being. But, we may need to support  other app server(s) as well. How logging separation is dependent on App. Server(s)?

Comment: Each has its own way of loading classes and resources.

Comment: @PaulVargas, Thanks for your response. Can you please give me some reference or idea for JBoss